# When to use WordPress and when a single paga application framework?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, vue.js, content-management-system, single-page-application

I'm trying to understand when I should use CMS like WordPress and when to use a single page application framework like React and Vue when creating a website. Any help?

Comment: Are you a capable programmer and does this website have very little, if any content that needs to be editable by people who aren't programmers? If yes, make your own in site in vue or react. Otherwise, WordPress is worth looking into if you don't want to spend lots of time building a site.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can be used without any (barely any) coding skills. It's also a fast way to get a templated website running.  If you don't know how to code, don't have a lot of time, and have a simple site, use WordPress

If you have coding knowledge, have time, and have a complex application, you won't be able to use WordPress, and you will find that out quite quickly.